# Inline equivalent of AuthorizeForScopesAttribute

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-web

We have a controller that we have been developing that uses the Microsoft.Identity.Web.AuthorizeForScopes attribute for the controller for example

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[]
    {
    "https://ourdomain.co.uk/us.theapi/access",
    })]
public class BrowseController : Controller
```

This has worked well until we now. We need to deploy the set of web apis to production. The apis will have a new Azure AD application registration for production. That will mean we'll need to "Add a scope" in the "Expose an API" section of the Azure Portal. The new Azure AD application has a new Application ID URI (Azure does not allow it to use the one that was used by the devlopment application registration).

That App ID URI forms part of the scope string so if our new app id is "https://ourdomain.co.uk/us.**prod**-theapi/" and the scope is still "access" then the attribute in the code would need to be "https://ourdomain.co.uk/us.prod-theapi/" however that is no good for development.

Is there a way of checking for scopes that gets a similar result to the one obtained by AuthorizeForScopes attribute but without using an Attribute? We need to be able to drive the scope string used by a configuration property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/0a22b5e743fb547781ef624c824ae866f9abbb57/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/AuthorizeForScopesAttribute.cs#L39), you can actually define a configuration section key instead of defining the scopes inline.

E.g.:

```cs
[AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "Auth:Scopes")]
public class BrowseController : Controller
```

And in appsettings JSON:

```json
{
  "Auth": {
    "Scopes": "https://ourdomain.co.uk/us.theapi/access"
  }
}
```

You can then have a different value for that configuration value depending on the environment or through environment variables etc.